# Getting Mount: Access Denied when installing QGIS on Windows 7

Tags: qgis, installation, windows-7

I tried to install QGIS on my laptop with Windows 7 Professional and it is a 64 bit machine. after going through the procedure described below I got the message "Mount Access Denied".

What is going on?

I downloaded osgeo4w-setup
clicked on install using "Advanced Install";
Selected "Install from local directory";
Selected "C:\OSGEO4W" as the root directory for the install;
Expanded "Desktop"
Selected "qgis"
Selected "1.8.0-5"
Expanded "Libs"
Selected "GDAL"
Selected "1.9.2-2"
Clicked "NEXT"
Message: "Mount: Access Denied"

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you do not have the right to create folders in C:\ Root directory. Try the same with admin rights, or check the rights you have on C:\